# HTML5 input type date formatting

Tags: html, date, datepicker

I have to use HTML5 input type='date' for my angular 6 application. I want to Show it as dd/MM/yyyy format. But when I change Local pc time format as yyyy-MM-dd chrome automatically change the time format to local pc time format. But I want to set it as dd/MM/yyyy for all users. (Because their pc time formats can be different) How can I Solve this problem. Is their any method to format it.

If I put format attribute as follows it will not work.

```
<input type="date" format="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
```

Comment: You could maybe have a look at this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that its not currently possible to do format the date (there is no `format` attribute available).

However, you probably want a solution, so here are some options that you might want to try

1) Use an `<input type='text'>` for display, and have a hidden `<input type='date'>` for when the user tries to open the date-picker (it might not be easy to open the native date picker programmatically), and have JavaScript put the date from the date-picker into the input type text

2) Just use a library with a customizable date picker like the [Angular Material DatePicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) with the setLocale method

Comment: Thank you for your response @Mendy. I'm going to try another third party date picker.

Comment: Other than Angular material Datepicker Is their any third party module that easily integrate with <input type='date' [(ngModel)="inputDate"]> . Because some datepickers are hard to applywith ngModel

Comment: You can try [ng-bootstraps datepicker](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview) or [ngx-bootstraps datepicker](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker), they both use input tags so it should be fairly easy to use ngModel

Comment: Yeah, but their Output model is not same as normal date input. Model: {
  "year": 2019,
  "month": 1,
  "day": 31
},  So I have to write another method to handle this.